# Drupal 6 db_query files table

Tags: drupal-6

As part of moving from a windows server to a linux server I have to clean up a large number of filenames.

My Problem is that when I execute:

`db_query("UPDATE {files} SET filename = '%s' AND filepath = '%s' WHERE fid = %d", $file->filename, $file->filepath, $file->fid);`

and afterwards select the content for $file->fid the filename field has the value of "0"

If I dump the query as text both before and after it's being executed the filename field contains the filename I have specified where as the filepath is being stored correctly.

Answer (score 1):

DAMN! putting an AND into an update query will not produce the expected result... MySQL allows this but it's not the way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma instead of AND.

Might also want to look into using drupal_write_record() instead of db_query. drupal_write_record will automatically update a pre-existing row if you add the 3rd parameter for a key to check. In your case, you could use the file id.